Flutter TextInputType Issue: Brief Instance of TextInputType.visiblePassword Before TextInputType.number Shows
I'm experiencing a brief instance of TextInputType.visiblePassword before keyboardType: TextInputType.number shows in my Flutter app. Here is the relevant part of my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CodeInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CodeInputState createState() => _CodeInputState();
}

class _CodeInputState extends State<CodeInput> {
  late List<TextEditingController> _codeControllers;
  late List<FocusNode> _codeFocusNodes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _codeControllers = List.generate(4, (index) => TextEditingController());
    _codeFocusNodes = List.generate(4, (index) => FocusNode());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final controller in _codeControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    for (final focusNode in _codeFocusNodes) {
      focusNode.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildCodeBox(int index) {
    return KeyboardListener(
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKeyEvent: (event) {
        if (event is KeyDownEvent &&
            event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace &&
            _codeControllers[index].text.isEmpty &&
            index > 0) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_codeFocusNodes[index - 1]);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _codeControllers[index],
          focusNode: _codeFocusNodes[index],
          autofocus: index == 0,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if (value.length == 1) {
              if (index < 3) {
                _codeFocusNodes[index + 1].requestFocus();
              } else {
                print('should submit code');
              }
            }
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number, // Explicitly set the keyboard type
          textInputAction: index < 3 ? TextInputAction.next : TextInputAction.done,
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: List.generate(4, (index) => _buildCodeBox(index)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: CodeInput()));
}

What I've Tried:
Setting autofocus: true for the first input field:
Expected: Immediate display of TextInputType.number.
Result: Brief flash of TextInputType.visiblePassword before switching to TextInputType.number.
Using a Builder widget to ensure proper context:
Expected: Proper initialization of the keyboard type.
Result: Same issue persists with a brief flash of TextInputType.visiblePassword.
Delay focus:
Expected: Avoid the brief instance of the wrong keyboard type.
Result: Did not resolve the issue.
How can I solve this issue?
